# Devstack: tempest.conf file

Tags: openstack, devstack

I am new to devstack and was trying to understand the way it works. I have one question regarding generation of tempest.conf file. I can not understand how this file gets generated and which part of the code generates it.

Is it always generated into /opt/stack/tempest/etc/ directory. What if I have a different folder structure and I want to generate my tempest.conf file in suppose /opt/stack/new/tempest/etc/ directory.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Tempest framework in the OpenStack is works for openstack development. You can find it in [github](https://github.com/openstack/tempest).

the `tempest.conf` file is the configuration file of Tempest, from the README.rst, you can know:

> To start you need to create a configuration file. The easiest way to create a configuration file is to generate a sample in the `etc/` directory
>
> $ cd $TEMPEST_ROOT_DIR
>   $ oslo-config-generator --config-file \
>       tempest/cmd/config-generator.tempest.conf \
>       --output-file etc/tempest.conf

You can just modify the output file path in the `--output-file` param.